# Repeating Background in Websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a gradient background that runs on the html tag in css. On the body tag, I have a simple seamless pattern that repeats on both x and y axis.

Everything seems good until I previewed the website on an ipad/iphone (portrait mode) where the screen height is much taller than its width.

On normal screens or in landscape mode in mobiles, the website would end at the footer of my page. However, when the screen height is taller, the seamless pattern would stop repeating leaving an empty gradient after the footer.

I have tried making both html & body's height 100% but it doesn't make any difference. I have also tried to use javascript to dynamically change the height of body to match html's height, but was no avail.

Can anyone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

jsfiddle.net/ek4jU/2/

In the fiddle the background gradient placed in the html is repeating throughout, but the white color background in the body isn't. I understand that if I were to make the body's height 100%, it will be the correct result that I need. However, this is to show what I will see on a mobile device, even if the height of 100% is given to the body.

Comment: code or jsfiddle?

Comment: @keeg  link to page won't help anyone in the future trying to research similar problem

Comment: @charlietfl cheerfly withdrawn

Comment: I _really_ hope "websies" is just a missing "t" typo and not the overly cute name of a specific product.

Comment: @nnnnnn   what I couldn't follow is how a `website` appears at the bottom of a page

Comment: @charlietfl - The question doesn't say that the website "appears at the bottom", it says that when it works it would "end at the footer" (not "end up at the footer"). I think what the OP is trying to say is that when the page works it is not possible to scroll beyond the footer element(s) of the page, i.e., the page ends with the footer, but when it doesn't work (portrait mode) there is some sort of gradient background shown below the footer.

Comment: Have you tried using sticky footer? i mean, put the footer at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: apologies for the website typo. i tried making a jsfiddle. but i can't seem to really exactly put my point through with it. I have added the jsfiddle link in there, with some explanation in there. Hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: Look up HTML Sticky Footer.

Comment: @DuverJaramillo I would like the footer follow right after the content, otherwise there would be a huge empty gap between the content and footer for pages appearing on long screens (landscape in mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Do the next changes and see the jsfiddle demo:

```
body { background-color: #FFF; } /*remove this*/

html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4c4c4c), color-stop(0.54, #595959), to(#131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4c4c4c 0%, #595959 54%, #131313 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4c4c4c 0%, #595959 54%, #131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#4c4c4c 0%, #595959 54%, #131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#4c4c4c 0%, #595959 54%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ /*         Chrome,Safari4+ */ /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ /* Opera 11.10+ */ /* IE10+ */ /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c',             endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EaGAV/

Comment: I tried applying what I understand from your solution, which I remove the background gradient from html to place it in the body, and used another div place my pattern repeat overlay. But the results seems the same. (I have set both 'body' and 'background div' to height of 100%).

However, things seems to be what I want when I placed height 100% for my html too, but then it creates a long scrollable page below the footer on normal desktop viewing.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/yKNvW/ , i make a couple of fixes to the code and let me know if that works.

Comment: I still can't seem to achieve what I needed with background color and pattern running throughout the page. Maybe I can't fully grasp the concept from your solution. But nonetheless, I am sure this answer will be useful for many. I tried giving you upvote, but seems like I need more reps to do so.. Sorry!